# Display short tags on one line

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-tags-input

The picture below is an image of the functionality from the site. In the column "Enter a code" the user can enter data using TagsInput.
I would like to slightly improve the functionality so that short tags are displayed on one line. I know that you can apply "inline", but then long tags go beyond the borders of the modal window.

```
.tag {
    display: flexbox;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 5px 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: fit-content;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}
```

I have already tried many options, and looked at many answers on stackoverflow, but did not achieve the result. Perhaps you can give me a hint.

Comment: `display: flexbox` is invalid, it should be `display: flex` but have you tried `display: inline-block`?

Comment: @Undo If I use display: flex then the ellipsis doesn't work. Yes, of course I tried display: inline-block

Comment: OK. My suggestion wasn't to use `display: flex`, I merely pointed out that `flexbox` is not a valid value to `display`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be nice if you add a bit more code that this. I'm guessing your `tag` class is on the children? What you need is to put the parent container in flex.

```
<body>
  <div class="tag-container">
    <div class="tag">100<div class="del">x</div></div>
    <div class="tag">200<div class="del">x</div></div>
    <div class="tag">300<div class="del">x</div></div>
    <div class="tag">400<div class="del">x</div></div>
    <div class="tag">500<div class="del">x</div></div>
    <div class="tag">600<div class="del">x</div></div>
    <div class="tag">700<div class="del">x</div></div>
    <div class="tag">800<div class="del">x</div></div>
    <div class="tag">800<div class="del">x</div></div>
    <div class="tag">1000<div class="del">x</div></div>
    <input
      class="input"
      placeholder="Enter a code"
    />
  </div>
</body>
```

```
.tag-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px; /* Exemple width */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.tag {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
}
.del {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30%;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.input {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 50%;
  border: none;
  margin: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately your solution doesn't work. I have updated the question and added more code

Comment: I've edited my answer to fit your code as much as possible, but if not I suspect it might be some interfering styles from your react components?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Your code is not quite suitable for me, but it led me to the right idea))

Comment: Yeah I never used react so I can't help you too much with that but glad it could help you at least a bit!